# Is there a word for a wind that comes from the sea?

Tags: word-request

Do we just say ‘sea wind’? ‘Sea wind’ seems very weird and unsophisticated. I am wondering if there's a specific word for "sea wind" or any wind related to the sea or ocean.

Comment: Amazing! Though English-speaking sailors have been remarkably prolific in cmoing up with all sorts of nautical jargon, there doesn't seem to be a single word for "onshore wind", which you would think is something of importance because it's the one condition that makes it hard to sail out of a bay.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do we just say sea wind? Sea wind seems very weird and unsophisticated. I am wondering if there's a specific word for "sea wind" or any wind related to the sea or ocean.

The wind that comes from the sea is called **sea breeze**.

> **Sea breeze:** a light, cool wind blowing from the sea onto the land - [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sea-breeze)

The wind that comes from the ocean is called **ocean breeze**.

There are lots of synonyms of *sea breeze* including *zephyr, gust, waft, flurry* etc.

Comment: Hm, actually, a light wind that comes from the ocean is also called a *sea breeze*. If "breeze" would be a serious understatement, then you just call it "wind".

Comment: None of those synonyms seem to be specific to _sea_ breezes.  (While ‘waft’ _does_ have a specific nautical meaning, it's nothing to do with wind.  Neither is ‘flurry’.)

Answer (score 4):

We can say ‘sea breeze’ or ‘onshore breeze’.